# AdMob does not appear in my application?

Tags: android, android-manifest, admob, banner

I have problem I wanna add admob to Preference Activity, but the app doesn't show it.

**Here is my AdMob activity:**

```
public class AdMobActivity extends Preference {
    public AdMobActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {super(context, attrs, defStyle);}
    public AdMobActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {super(context, attrs);}
    public AdMobActivity(Context context) {super(context);}

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    // this will create the linear layout defined in

    View view = super.onCreateView(parent);

    // the context is a PreferenceActivity
    Activity activity = (Activity)getContext();

    // Create the adView
    AdView adView = new AdView(activity, AdSize.BANNER, "XXXXXXXXXXX");

    ((LinearLayout)view).addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(request);

    return view;
    }
}
```

**Here is my layout for AdMob (banner.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

**And here is xml for my Preference Activity:**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="Ads">
             <com.blabla.asafgasf.AdMobActivity android:layout="@layout/banner"/>
        </PreferenceCategory>   
        <PreferenceCategory
        .....
        </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I have set `target=android-13` in project.properties and in my Manifest I have:

```
<activity android:name=".AdMobActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

If I remove `|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize` from configChanges in my application will appear red box and there is written: **You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges.**

I have installed the newest version of AdMob library (4.3.1) and the newest version of SDK (API 14) and the newest ADT plugin.
**So where is the problem?**

Answer (score 0):

You may have no Ads to fill the Admob, what do you receive in LogCat?

Comment: OK, problem solved I installed API 12 and now when I RUN my app, AdMob appears.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you check your view in `hierarchyviewer` tool. You should be able to see if your view is being added into your LinearLayout or not. Sometimes a view is added but the layout params are not correct so the view is not visible.

You can find the viewer in \tools. Just launch you app in the emulator switch to the command prompt/terminal and execute the executable.